# Map result from query to Not Mapped property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I've built my query using a string. Among other things, here's what I'm selecting:

```sql
SELECT 
    ..., 
    [CST].CompanyName AS 'CustomerName', 
    CONCAT([CON].FirstName, ' ', [CON].LastName) AS 'BuyerName'
...
```

My model has 2 `[NotMapped]` properties: `CustomerName` and `BuyerName`.

I'm using EF Core 3.1. How can I tell EF that what's returned from the `CustomerName` and `BuyerName` columns should be mapped to the `[NotMapped]` properties with the same name?

I've tried this:

```cs
var estimates = _context.Estimates
   .FromSqlRaw(sqlString)
   .AsNoTracking()
   .Select(s => new Estimate
   {
       // lazy load
       BuyerName = s.Customer.CompanyName,
       CustomerName = s.CustomerContact.FirstName + " " + 
          s.CustomerContact.LastName
   })
   .ToList();
```

It works but it performs 2 unnecessary joins (which I already performed inside my `sqlString` variable).

Comment: `FromSqlRaw` just returns a flat result set. EF doesn't have (and can't have) any notion of hierarchy in this flat table. So if you use  `s.Customer.CompanyName` it *has* to join to get access to the `Customer` record.

Comment: @GertArnold: So what can I do? If I choose this option, my query has the same joins (inefficient).

Comment: Your only option here is Dapper. EF do not parse SQL to understand what is loaded or not. Also consider using DTO instead of projecting to Entity classes.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: You are a life saver man!!! I've struggled with this for days. Using Dapper solved so many issues (not only this one). Thanks a lot! ❤️